# function that uses a while loop to return characters in a list while also being subject to other conditions

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

To preface, because I’m learning to use while loops, I want to write this function with **only if statements, in statements, and while loops**. I think I may also need to use **break or continue**. I don’t want to use for loops or forms of list comprehension.

the function itself should looks like `take_last(lst)`

It should normally take in a list of words and returns the last value in the list with the first and last characters of it removed.

for instance,

```
take_last[“Fish”, “Meat”, “Fruit”, “Cake”]
```

will return `“ak”` as this is the last word in the list with the characters, “C” and “e” removed. This part of the function is relatively simple. I think it can be done with

```
return (lst[-1])[slice(1,-1)]
```

However, it is subject to two different conditions that may make writing the function difficult.

1. if the first name in the list has less than 3 characters, the function will stop and return “finished”

i.e `take_list([“SH”, “Meat”])` will stop at “SH” and instead returns `“finished”`.

2. otherwise, if this condition is not fulfilled and the first word has 3 or more characters, the function will continue iterating through the list until it finds another word with less than 3 characters. it will then stop at this point and return the previous character in the list with the first and last character in it removed.

I.e if the input is `take_last([“Fish”, “Meat”, “Fruit”, “SH”, “Cake”])` the function breaks at “SH” and instead `“rui”` is returned. (Fruit without the ‘F

**What I am Trying**

Although I am not sure how to structure the while loop, I have written the function with the first condition already fulfilled.

```
def take_last(lst):
    if len(lst[0]) < 3:
        return "finished"
    else:
        return (lst[-1])[slice(1,-1)]
```

`take_last([“Fish”, “Meat”, “Fruit”, “Cake”])` will return `“ake”`

and `take_last([“Fi”, “Meat”, “Fruit”, “Cake”])` will return

```
“finished”
```

I know that somewhere in my function I will need an elif statement followed by a while loop but I’m not sure how this would look. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `slice()`. Just `[1:-1]`

Comment: So it's not supposed to return the last string in the list, it's supposed to return the string before the first string with less than 3 characters, or the last string if there isn't a shorter strings.

Comment: yes my bad for not clarifying

Comment: You can just put the `while` loop in the `else:` block. You don't need `elif`. Either the first word is shorter than 3 or you want to loop to find the first short word.

Comment: You say you want to iterate for each element in a list, yet you don’t want to use a for loop?

Comment: a for loop would be the most convenient way to do this. However I want to see if it can be done with a while loop.

Comment: If the structure of my function could be revised to exclude the other if statements and include only a while loop I think that would work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it.

```
def take_last(lst):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst) and len(lst[i]) >= 3:
        i += 1
    if i == 0:
        return "finished"
    else:
        return lst[i-1][1:-1]
```

The `while` loop repeats as long as the string at index `i` is at least 3 characters long. So when it's done, `i` contains the index of the first short string; if there are no short elements, it will contain the length of the list.

If the first string is short, `i` will be `0`, so there's no element before it and we return `finished`.

Otherwise we return the slice of the element before `i`. This will be the last element when there are no short elements.

Comment: so if I’m reading this correctly, i += 1 makes it so the function travels through each indice [] in the list so it can check each string individually?

Comment: Yes. That adds 1 to the `i` variable to get to the next index.

Comment: This doesn't look like it handles lists without any short strings properly. I think the `while` loop needs an additional condition, `i < len(lst)` or you risk getting an `IndexError` when `i` gets too big.

Answer (score 0):

So returning the last word with 1st and 3rd chars removed is the last possible thing we can do. There may be conditions before it which may cause the the function to stop early.

So, now we know what becomes our default return

```
  return (lst[-1])[slice(1,-1)]
```

Similarly, the first condition you are checking is correct as well. So that fixes our starting  `if`.

```
    if len(lst[0]) < 3:
        return "finished"
```

Now the condition 2. We can tackle this in the `else` clause. We need to iterate through the list looking for a word less than 3 chars. If we find it, we return the element just before it after truncation .

```
else:
    i = 1
    while (i < len(lst)):
        if len(lst[i]) < 3:
            return (lst[i-1])[slice(1,-1)]
        i += 1
```

Everything put together:

```
def take_last(lst):
    if len(lst[0]) < 3:
        return "finished"
    else:
        i = 1
        while (i < len(lst)):
            if len(lst[i]) < 3:
                return (lst[i-1])[slice(1,-1)]
            i += 1
    return (lst[-1])[slice(1,-1)]
```

Comment: You're missing `]` after `slice(1, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a regular `for` loop in a way that, to me, feels a lot more natural than doing it with a `while` loop:

```
def take_last(lst):
    prev = None
    for val in lst:
        if len(val) < 3:
            break
        prev = val
    if prev is None:
        return "finished"
    else:
        return prev[1:-1]
```